# adding ftp user on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

I followed this tut http://www.trainsignal.com/blog/how-to-set-up-safe-ftp-in-linux to setup an ftp server with user account

```
sudo mkdir -p /home/ftp/ftpuser
sudo useradd ftpuser -d /home/ftp/ftpuser -s /bin/false
sudo passwd ftpuser
```

when I tried to connect with login ftpuser remotely it didn't work. It didn't work even with root UNLESS I removed root from ftpusers.

I am confused ftpusers are the users NOT allowed to do ftp ? Where are the list of users allowed then and why can't I connect with ftpuser I created ?

Comment: Can you post your ftp server config?

Comment: Also post the error message you get when trying to log in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, somewhat confusingly the /etc/ftpusers file is a list of users who are not allowed to use the FTP service.

To answer your other question, we will need more information. Offhand, I wonder if perhaps you forgot to uncomment the local_enable=YES option. Please share the error you receive on the ftp client, any relevant errors from syslog, and your configuration if you could.

Answer (score 0):

Your second option is to setup an SSH account for the user and have them connect to SFTP on port 22.

You would go through the same setup as above with the exception

```
sudo useradd ftpuser -d /home/ftp/ftpuser -s /bin/bash
```

This gives the user both SSH and SFTP access via any FTP application such as Filezilla via port 22(or your SSH port if you have changed it)